# How to get cout(*) based on sysdate -1

Tags: oracle

I want to get count(*) with table name printed with records which are sysdate-1 in oracle.

Select abc , count(*) from abc where dat_last_mnt < sysdate -1

With regards
Sree

Comment: Your second query might need `group by abc` added to the end.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output in text format along with your current code and description of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data-type with 7 bytes for century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second and it **ALWAYS** has those 7 components.

If you want to find a count of the values that were yesterday then you need to filter to find the range of values between 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 on that day and you need to include a `GROUP BY` clause with all the columns you are not aggregating by:

```sql
SELECT column_name,
       count(*)
FROM   table_name
WHERE  dat_last_mnt >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY
AND    dat_last_mnt <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
GROUP BY column_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (column_name, dat_last_mnt) AS
SELECT 'A', TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '2' DAY + INTERVAL '20' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL  '0' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL  '4' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL  '8' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL '12' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL '16' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL '20' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '0' DAY + INTERVAL  '0' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL  '1' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL  '2' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL  '3' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '0' DAY + INTERVAL  '0' HOUR FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | COLUMN_NAME | COUNT(*) |
> | --- | --- |
> | A | 6 |
> | B | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d7352302fbc97e916da56dfda3f7fb5b)*